# How to handle scenario dependency in Jmeter?

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, scenarios

Using a ''requester'' role, I need to execute a scenario that will send a notification to another role to perform other actions. This scenario will act like a trigger of other two.

After all the notifications are sent (+100) I have to execute another two scenarios, for which 50 requests will be approved and 50 will be rejected.

How can I execute this scenario in such a way that the trigger scenario finishes first, so then I can perform the other two scenarios?

A timer can help for this case without affecting the load?

Answer (score 0):

If you have all requests under the same [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) you could use a [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler and [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) combination.

Add Flow Control Action sampler as the last sampler of the "requester" scenario (whatever it means) and set the "Number of simulated users to group by" to be equal to the number of threads in your Thread Group.

If "scenarios" are spread between different Thread Groups - take a look at [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#comm).